# setdate javascript is firing every time the document is opened

Tags: javascript, date

We're using the following javascript to automatically set the current date via the onload function when a student accesses one of our online forms. We do have an actual form tag on the form

```
            function fillTodaysDate()
            {
                if(document.getElementById('todaydate').value.length < 5){
                       var d = new Date();
                       var dateString = (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
                       document.getElementById('todaydate').value = dateString;     
                }                      
            }
```

The date populates as expected, however, it continues to update every time the document is opened after the student has submitted it (the forms are sent to a document management system where we review them).

How can we prevent the date from continuing to update once the form has been submitted?

Below is the code for the actual field:

```
  <table style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #000000 1px solid; WIDTH: 250px; HEIGHT: 26px; BORDER-TOP: #000000 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #000000 1px solid">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="singlepropertyrow">
        <td class="propertylabel">Today's Date</td>
        <td style="WIDTH: 50%" class="propertycontent">
          <input style="WIDTH: 100%" 
          class="propertytextinput" type="text" readonly="true" name="todaydate" id="todaydate">
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
              <xsl:value-of select="_301YV5R_002E2MVLT0001HR_" />
            </xsl:attribute>
          </input>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that calls the `fillTodaysDate()` function? This code just shows the function declaration.

Comment: how is `fillTodaysDate` called? as a guess, you're calling it on page load and, since you mention "forms", you're submitting the form, the form has no action attribute, and you don't prevent default submit action, therefore current page is reloaded. which means anything performed on page load is executed

Comment: Are you using an actual `<form>`element in your code?

Comment: How does the page know that the form has already been submitted? Are you using cookies? Local storage? Do users log in so have an authenticated session? Pretty simple to stop the update: don't run the function! But you need to include the criteria for when to run it and help with possible solutions.

Comment: Updated post with additional information